# Parsing integerfields as integer values

Tags: django, django-models

I'm looking for a way to parse the value of integerFields and returning the value.

```
scoreChans = models.IntegerField(0)
scoreChansSet = models.BooleanField(False)
scoreYatzy = models.IntegerField(0)
scoreYatzySet = models.BooleanField(False) 

scoreTotal = scoreChans + scoreYatzy
```

But this gives:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntegerField' and 'IntegerField'

Is there a way the fetch the values from these fields?

Comment: Where is this code? Please show the full context.

Comment: I picked out the related part from my models.py. Does the rest really matter?

Comment: It kind-of does, because _where_ you write the python code matters. If that code you wrote is standalone, it makes no sense. If it is in a model declaration, then it makes no sense, but in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only fetch the values on an instantiated model.

I assume you want to have a computed property? Something like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    score_a = models.IntegerField()
    score_b = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def total_score(self):
        return self.score_a + self.score_b
```

Comment: When you instantiate or fetch an object of this class, `total_score` will be a property you can access on the object. `obj = MyModel.objects.all()[0]`, and then `obj.total_score`